# iOS Phonegap/jQuery mobile app performance degrades when paused/ put in background

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm currently writing a phonegap app for iOS. I'm using jQuery mobile for the UI. The app works fine when used from new (just installed or a clean open - ie if the app was quit or the device switched off) but when the app is paused / put into the background and then reopened the performance seems to degrade so much so that the app becomes almost unusable and unresponsive - you can't even navigate between pages etc.

I think the issue may be tied to JQM and the fact I'm using a Multipage template rather than splitting each page into single HTML files.

Has anyone else experienced this or could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: I seem to be making some headway, I've changed from multipage jquery templates to single page. Will report back when confirmed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, swapping from a JQM multipage setup (one long .html file containing multiple pages) to single page templates (a separate .html file for each page) solved this for me.

There is now no degradation in performance when the apps being paused and resumed - hope this helps someone.